# Why can't remount the disk with command?

Tags: linux, debian, mount

The /dev/sdb2 was mounted on `/media/debian/WINFAT`.

```
df /media/debian/WINFAT
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       24406016 402256  24003760   2% /media/debian/WINFAT
```

[image]

Umount it:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb2
```

[image]

Remount it with  command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2   /media/debian/WINFAT
mount: mount point /media/debian/WINFAT does not exist
```

Why can't remount the disk with command?

Note:you can move mouse over the `WINFAT` and left click to mount it.

Comment: Does "/media/debian/WINFAT" exist as a mounting location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target directory must exist before mounting. And it will continue to exist after unmounting. It was actually removed by something else *after* your 'umount' command had completed.

Your file manager handles disk mounting with the UDisks2 service, which is designed for handling portable media – so it automatically creates the mountpoint directories when needed, and it's also UDisks2 which automatically removes them as soon as the mount itself is undone.

So when using the regular 'mount' command you don't get any of this automation; you need to `mkdir` the target directory before you'll be able to mount anything on it.

```
# mkdir /media/debian/WINFAT
# mount /dev/sdb2 /media/debian/WINFAT
```

After unmounting a disk mounted this way, the directory should remain:

```
# umount /media/debian/WINFAT
# ls -l /media/debian
```

Or you can also call UDisks2 like your file manager does, and get the same automation:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2
...
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb2
```